# `knex` SQLITE_CANTOPEN error in production `electron` app

Tags: sqlite, electron, runtime-error, knex.js, production

I recently build the `electron` app, after making `dmg` for mac, I ran the application. Unfortunately, I got the catch for `SQLITE_CANTOPEN:` error. Application highly depends upon the database. Here is the `knex` code to connect the sqlite database.

```
let knex = require("knex")({
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
        filename: './appdb.sqlite'
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true
});
```

Here is the version information for the libraries i'm using,

- `electron@6.0.2`
- `electron-builder@21.2.0`
- `electron-rebuild@1.8.5`
- `knex@0.19.1`
- `sqlite3@4.0.9`

I'm building the app on Mac OS HighSeirra v10.13.6, seems there is no issue with the library but `knex` couldn't create a new database file on the system. It should create a new database as `appdb.sqlite` when it doesn't find a database file on a specific path. Any solution or best practice to handle it properly?

Comment: Try to study this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c76FTxLRwAw

Comment: Well, thanks but i used it correctly, but seems that `knex` connection does not create `.sqlite` file if no such file found. I have a static database path in the `application data` directory of `platform`. I want to create new DB on first open of app, so I tried using `fs`, not working.

Comment: Without electron sqlite3 lib does create it automatically. So sounds like you are using electron in invalid manner.

Comment: it's possible. can you please provide a `flow` or `code snippet` about how i can use it with production mode? it seems that i have relative database path issue. when user opens program first time i want to create new db and it will be used until deleted from specific location.

Comment: You need to ask from electron people how to allow it to write new files... I haven't coded anything for electron during last couple of years so I don't remember anything how stuff works there.